# Keep Session In ASP.NET Core after building a project

Tags: session, asp.net-core-mvc

I have ASP.NET core application and I'm developing admin side where user must be logged in. Information about user login status is stored in session.

The problem is that, every time I make a change and build my application session is destroyed and I have to relogin user.

How can I keep session alive so I don't need to login after any change in my code.

Session setup is:

```
   Services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            options.Cookie.Name = "MySession";
        })
```

I used sessionState Mode="StateServer" in regular MVC app, what is an option for .NET Core?

Comment: Do you use Identity where you could set `isPersistent: true` to keep it alive:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53906813/how-to-keep-the-session-alive-after-the-browser-is-closed-for-15-minutes-using-i

Comment: Thank you for comment, but I don't understand what exactly should I suppose to do. I have my custom sign in login and I'm not using any ASP.NET authentication libraries. All I need is keep session alive after I rebuild an apllication